# Which path to use for adding a Git remote?

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab, git-remote

Basically, I want to be able to run

```
git push myserver branchname
```

to have my changes pushed to my server

I know I need to add the git repo on my server as a remote branch, and then push to that remote branch

However, I don't know which URL to use for the git remote.

My website is located at:

```
var/www/mywebsite.com
```

However nginx serves the public directory which is located at:

```
var/www/mywebsite.com/public
```

So when trying to add the git remote, which URL should I input?

I think I need to use

```
git remote add myserver root@mywebsite.com:path/to/git/repo
```

Or maybe I need to include SSH somewhere in there?

But what is the path to my git repo on my server?

Would I use:

```
git remote add myserver root@mywebsite.com:myrepository.git
```

Or since it's in the public directory, and I need to go out one folder, would it be:

```
git remote add myserver root@mywebsite.com:../myrepository.git
```

I've tried both. Neither work? Do I even have a valid URL to use at this point? If so, what is it? If not, how do I create one?

My .git is located in var/www/mywebsite.com/.git but that doesn't work.

Comment: Which Git service did you use to create your repository?

Comment: Or if you have a old git clone that you do not remember where service is pointed to, check in your .git/config file

Comment: use the command: `git config --get remote.origin.url` to get `remote origin url`

Comment: Are you pushing to the server with SSH, HTTP or git://?

Comment: Sorry for delay guys. Was driving home. I am using gitlab. And I prefer to use SSH as that's what I use for everything else and it works fine. I do not have an old url to reference in .git/config and @divij that gives me the gitlab URL but I need URL for my own private server

Comment: @J.Doe Type the following in your terminal: `git config --get remote.` and hit `Tab` this will show you the available remote references. Thereafter, use the push command as follows: `git push <remote ref name you got after pressing tab above> <branch you want to push to>` This will help you push code to the correct branch on your ref

Comment: @divij error: key does not contain section: remote -- Don't worry about this question though. I believe I've found the answer. Posted below.